# identifying javascripy modules in html

Tags: javascript

I have several JavaScript modules structured as shown below:

```
modules/
  main.js
  canvas.js
  shapes.js
  shapes/
    circle.js
    square.js
    triangle.js
```

is main.js, canvas and shapes are imported. in shapes, circle,tringle, square modules are imported. I add a reference to main module in my HTML page like

```html
<script type="module"src="./main.js"/>
```

but it has this error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

can you help me? and can i don not add reference to child modules in html? for example I just add:

```html
<script type="module"src="./main.js"/>
```

in HTML and not identifying other modules in HTML.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't self-closing script elements work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-elements-work)